# Is it possible to call another flow from a widget in Twilio Studio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

It seems like it's possible if I call an HTTP Post to call the next Flow, but I was wondering if there's an easier way directly from a widget.

It looks like I can't call the flow directly because I can't authenticate from a Flow widget.

Comment: Hey, did you get any further with this issue?

Comment: No, I haven't seen any responses on it. It looks like you have to have all of the logic built into a single flow. Even if you're able to call another flow, that flow won't handle the reply messages properly.

Comment: Ah yes, I think you're right. There is work going on to connect flows and Functions better, so hopefully this can be better for you soon.